# Trying to figure out the computational complexity of a modified DFS

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm working on a graphs problem, with unweighted undirected graphs, using adjacency list representation and I'm using a DFS to find any back edge to be able to remove them. Problem is I can't figure out the computational complexity of this procedure.

My DFS only differs from the original one in the DFS_visit subroutine because of the inner for and the fact that I'm not using timestamps. I'll post here the subroutine:

```
DFS_visit (G=(V,E), u):
    color[u] = Grey
    for each v \in Adj[u]
        if color[v] = White
            \pi[v] = u
            DFS_visit (G, v)
        if (u, v) is a back edge
            Adj[u].remove(v)
            Adj[v].remove(u)
    color[u] = Black
```

The "remove" procedure explores u's adjacency list until it finds v, then links the previous node (the one whose next was v) to the node next to v. (as done [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLxqR.jpg))
Thus, assuming every other operation in the remove procedure can be done in costant time, it should be a worst case Big O(|Adj[u]|) procedure (which happens when v is the last element in Adj[u]).

Now, in a normal DFS, DFS_visit is called multiple times (once per node). The normal DFS_visit is a \Theta(E) procedure (since every node is visited only once, and \sum (|Adj[u]|) = 2*E), but what happens in the worst case of my procedure? 
Right now my only idea is that remove will be called twice for each back edge. But I can't figure out any upper bound or anything to help calculating the computational complexity of the whole DFS.

Comment: Assuming `remove()` is constant time operation, you can remove each edge at most once, so the upper bound remains at `O(|E|)`.

Comment: What if remove() is not a costant time operation? Right now I've roughly implemented it as follows:

    `node n = first;
    node nprev = new();
    while (n.getnext() != null and "n is not v") {
        nprev = n;
        n = n.getnext();
    }
    nprev.setnext(n.getnext()) // operation shown in picture`

so, because of the while loop, it can have a worst case of O(Adj[u]).